# PrimeNG Order List Change Buttons Position

Tags: angular, primeng

Required to change button position for PrimeNG `p-orderList` component. It is generating following HTML code in browser.

```
<div class="ui-orderlist ui-widget ui-orderlist-responsive">
    <div calss="ui-orderlist-controls">
    </div>
    <div calss="ui-orderlist-list-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

`ui-orderlist-controls` class properties helping to change position but it has some issues.

Tried to swipe dives `ui-orderlist-controls` and `ui-orderlist-list-container`  inside container div `ui-orderlist ui-widget ui-orderlist-responsive` but it is not working.

[image]

Can you assist for resolve this issue.

Comment: can you create a plunker please https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a fast CSS solution I tried on PrimeNG website. Put in your CSS:

```
.ui-orderlist {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="ui-orderlist ui-widget ui-orderlist-responsive">
                <div class="ui-orderlist-controls" style="float: right;">
        .
        .
        .
```

or using css:

```
.ui-orderlist-controls {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the div is not vertically centered.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I already tried it div is not vertically aligned

Comment: @atishshimpi correct I didn't even think about that. Powkachu's answers is the correct one